# Ant - Java - zipfileset - excluding a directory

Tags: java, ant, zip

I have an ant target for creating zip like this -

```
<zip destfile="${dist}/myzip.zip">
    <zipfileset dir="docs/manual" prefix="docs/userguide"/>    
</zip>
```

This basically creates archive `myzip.zip` with all the files and directories  under `docs/manual`  prefixed with docs/userguide in the archive.

But I don' want to include all the directories under `docs/manual` to be copied into the archive,
I have a directory called `old` under `docs/manual` which I want to exclude...How to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [ZipFileSet reference page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html)

> `<zipfileset>` supports all attributes of `<fileset>` in addition to those listed below.

So see [FileSet](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) for reference.

This is how you do it:

```
<zipfileset dir="docs/manual" prefix="docs/userguide">    
    <exclude name="old/**"/>
</zipfileset>
```

or inline as attribute:

```
<zipfileset dir="docs/manual" prefix="docs/userguide" exclude="old/**" />
```

**Update:** Using wildcards now instead of simple name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But this does not seem to be working for excluding the entire directory, How ever I could see that if I use any file name in place of "old", the file is getting excluded.

Comment: OK, then you need to use ant wildcards. something like `old/**`

Answer (score 3):

you can exclude an entire directory by this:

```
<zipfileset dir="docs/manual" prefix="docs/userguide" exlcudes="**/old/**"/>
```

Comment: This answer excludes all files in that directory AND the directory itself. The accepted answer above only excludes the contents of the directory when I tried it, but the directory itself was still included

Answer (score 1):

```
<zip destfile="${dist}/myzip.zip" excludes="docs/manual/old/**">
    <zipfileset dir="docs/manual" prefix="docs/userguide"/>    
</zip>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the only one that worked for me for removal of specific file pattern

```
<zip destfile="${bin.dir}/boo.jar">
   <zipfileset dir="${classes.dir}" excludes="**/*/BooCreator*.class"/>
</zip>
```